# NGINX content disposition attachment not working on subdomain

Tags: nginx

Primary domain - imagecompressor.io, subdomain - dev.imagecompressor.io

Content disposition does not seem to be working for the subdomain. `curl` returns a `200 OK` for both, but the file is only downloaded for the primary domain. For the subdomain the request get forwarded to the reactjs frontend application.

https://imagecompressor.io/images/Logo.png - works  
https://dev.imagecompressor.io/images/Logo.png - does not work

**NGINX configuration - domain**

```
server {

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/imagecompressio-js/serve;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name imagecompressor.io;
    # error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
    
    location /images {
        alias /var/www/images;
                add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
                add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0";
                if_modified_since off;
                expires off;
                etag off;
                add_header Content-disposition "attachment; filename=$1";
    }

    location /files {
        alias /var/www/files;
        expires 3d;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        add_header Content-disposition "attachment; filename=$1";
    }
    location ^~  /blog {
        root /var/www/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location = /blog/mozjpeg-guide/compress {
        return 301 /blog/mozjpeg-guide;
    }
    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri /index.html =404;
        expires -1;
    }

     location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
        access_log        off;
            log_not_found     off;
        add_header        Cache-Control "no-cache, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/imagecompressor.io/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/imagecompressor.io/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

**NGINX configuration - subdomain**

```
server {

    root /var/www/imagecompressio-js/serve;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name dev.imagecompressor.io;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
    
    location /images {
        alias /var/www/images;
        add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0";
            if_modified_since off;
            expires off;
            etag off;
        add_header Content-disposition "attachment; filename=$1";
    }

    location /files {
        alias /var/www/files;
        expires 3d;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        add_header Content-disposition "attachment; filename=$1";
    }
    location ^~  /blog {
        root /var/www/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location = /blog/mozjpeg-guide/compress {
        return 301 /blog/mozjpeg-guide;
    }
    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri /index.html =404;
        expires -1;
    }

     location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
        access_log        off;
            log_not_found     off;
        expires 30d;
        add_header        Cache-Control "no-cache, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.imagecompressor.io/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.imagecompressor.io/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

`curl` output

dev.imagecompressor.io

```
curl --head https://dev.imagecompressor.io/images/Logo.png

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Date: Tue, 21 Jul 2020 21:10:07 GMT
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 6865
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Tuesday, 21-Jul-2020 21:10:07 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

imagecompressor.io

```
curl --head https://imagecompressor.io/images/Logo.png

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Date: Tue, 21 Jul 2020 21:15:00 GMT
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 6865
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Tuesday, 21-Jul-2020 21:15:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Exact same. Can't figure out what's the issue here.

Comment: Please post the complete `server` block for the non-working server, and for the working server.

Comment: @MichaelHampton updated.

Comment: Have you reset the browser cache? What does the access log contain when the file fails to download?

Comment: @RichardSmith It seems like a cache issue. Works in incognito. Damn, spend a few hours chasing this. If you can move your comment to answer, we can close this. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

It seemed like a cache issue but clearing the cache did work for a few downloads.
Root cause came to be `service worker` being enabled on the subdomain front-end. Disabling it made the issue go away.

[image]